# What does 'extraction' mean in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does ***extraction*** mean in the context? Does it mean 'the things that are extracted from fish, that is, fish organs' or 'utilization'?

> Although aquaculture occurs in a controlled environment, cases of
> escapes, contamination, and spread of disease have been documented,
> all of which may harm the natural ecosystem in the surrounding area.
> For example, studies in Chile have shown that escaped salmonids can
> colonize their new, nonnative environment, resulting in resource
> competition and potentially altering local ecosystem processes. Shrimp
> production in Asia and other parts of the world has resulted in the
> deforestation of mangroves and wetlands in order to create space for
> shrimp ponds. The cultivation of carnivorous fish depends on the
> ***extraction*** of wild fin-fish that are converted to meal for fish food. In some parts of the world, this has meant depleted stocks for
> local fishermen, who still depend on these species for a supplement to
> their diet or for income. Experts have recently recommended that
> native herbivorous or filter feeders be farmed, rather than nonnative
> carnivorous species, in order to avoid some of these potential
> problems.  Another suggested solution is to farm exclusively in
> terrestrial, man-made tanks where all stages of production could be
> managed, including the disposal of waste.

[Encyclopedia of Environment and Society: FIVE-VOLUME SET](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=9JvtBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=Although%20aquaculture%20occurs%20in%20a%20controlled%20environment,%20cases%20of%20escapes,%20contamination,%20and%20spread%20of%20disease%20have%20been%20documented,%20all%20of%20which%20may%20harm%20the%20natural%20ecosystem%20in%20the%20surrounding%20area.%20For%20example,%20studies%20in%20Chile%20have%20shown%20that%20escaped%20salmonids%20can%20colonize%20their%20new,%20nonnative%20environment,%20resulting%20in%20resource%20competition%20and%20potentially%20altering%20local%20ecosystem%20processes.%20Shrimp%20production%20in%20Asia%20and%20other%20parts%20of%20the%20world%20has%20resulted%20in%20the%20deforestation%20of%20mangroves%20and%20wetlands%20in%20order%20to%20create%20space%20for%20shrimp%20ponds.%20The%20cultivation%20of%20carnivorous%20fish%20depends%20on%20the%20extraction%20of%20wild%20fin-fish%20that%20are%20converted%20to%20meal%20for%20fish%20food.%20In%20some%20parts%20of%20the%20world,%20this%20has%20meant%20depleted%20stocks%20for%20local%20fishermen,%20who%20still%20depend%20on%20these%20species%20for%20a%20supplement%20to%20their%20diet%20or%20for%20income.%20Experts%20have%20recently%20recommended%20that%20native%20herbivorous%20or%20filter%20feeders%20be%20farmed,%20rather%20than%20nonnative%20carnivorous%20species,%20in%20order%20to%20avoid%20some%20of%20these%20potential%20problems.%20%20Another%20suggested%20solution%20is%20to%20farm%20exclusively%20in%20terrestrial,%20man-made%20tanks%20where%20all%20stages%20of%20production%20could%20be%20managed,%20including%20the%20disposal%20of%20waste.&source=bl&ots=Ltm277KrcE&sig=ACfU3U0FxttQCM-KUyP1z8JJvbT9vBmEFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiroL6LstLwAhVPxIsBHewOAAgQ6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Although%20aquaculture%20occurs%20in%20a%20controlled%20environment,%20cases%20of%20escapes,%20contamination,%20and%20spread%20of%20disease%20have%20been%20documented,%20all%20of%20which%20may%20harm%20the%20natural%20ecosystem%20in%20the%20surrounding%20area.%20For%20example,%20studies%20in%20Chile%20have%20shown%20that%20escaped%20salmonids%20can%20colonize%20their%20new,%20nonnative%20environment,%20resulting%20in%20resource%20competition%20and%20potentially%20altering%20local%20ecosystem%20processes.%20Shrimp%20production%20in%20Asia%20and%20other%20parts%20of%20the%20world%20has%20resulted%20in%20the%20deforestation%20of%20mangroves%20and%20wetlands%20in%20order%20to%20create%20space%20for%20shrimp%20ponds.%20The%20cultivation%20of%20carnivorous%20fish%20depends%20on%20the%20extraction%20of%20wild%20fin-fish%20that%20are%20converted%20to%20meal%20for%20fish%20food.%20In%20some%20parts%20of%20the%20world,%20this%20has%20meant%20depleted%20stocks%20for%20local%20fishermen,%20who%20still%20depend%20on%20these%20species%20for%20a%20supplement%20to%20their%20diet%20or%20for%20income.%20Experts%20have%20recently%20recommended%20that%20native%20herbivorous%20or%20filter%20feeders%20be%20farmed,%20rather%20than%20nonnative%20carnivorous%20species,%20in%20order%20to%20avoid%20some%20of%20these%20potential%20problems.%20%20Another%20suggested%20solution%20is%20to%20farm%20exclusively%20in%20terrestrial,%20man-made%20tanks%20where%20all%20stages%20of%20production%20could%20be%20managed,%20including%20the%20disposal%20of%20waste.&f=false)

Comment: It's not my subject, fish and game, but the way it reads to me is wild fin-fish are **extracted** (i.e., removed via fishing) from local ecosystems in order to turn them into food for carnivorous fish being grown in and harvested from fish farms, like in giant fish tanks, aquariums, or reservoirs that aren't really a part of or integrated into the local ecosystem. I'm not 100% positive this is right, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer, but I'm about 85% based on how it then talks of how the **extraction** "has meant depleted stocks for local fisherman." Maybe an ecologist can verify.

Comment: Benjamin, I totally agree with your explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Q. What does extraction mean in the context? Does it mean 'the things that are extracted from fish, that is, fish organs' or 'utilization'?

A. **No** It does not mean 'the things that are extracted from fish. It means wild fin-fish are **taken out** of the local waters. To feed the "carnivorous fish" being farmed.

> extraction; noun; the process of removing or **taking out** something: Ref [C.E.D](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extraction)